# What is an NSObjectController's selection?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, cocoa-bindings

In Xcode 6.2, in the Bindings Inspector I see this:

[image]

Can anyone explain what setting the `Controller Key` to `selection` means?  The Apple docs say:

> selection:
>   Returns a proxy object representing the [NSObjectController's] selection.

Not at all helpful.

Comment: It's one-way and useful in the subclasses, where you could do something like bind an NSObjectController's `content` to the `selection` of an NSArrayController that allows only single selection...  I don't think there's much more to say since there's apparently no way to set the selection with a simple NSObjectController instance.  It's intentionally useless in the superclass as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I've pieced together part of the puzzle. From [Apple Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002147-BCICADHC):

> Controllers require content to manipulate and there are a number of
>   options for setting this content. It can be done ...
>   through bindings...
>   ...
>   NSObjectController and its subclasses are initialized with the method
>   initWithContent:, passing a content object or nil if you intend to use
>   the content bindings. You can explicitly set the content of an
>   existing controller using the setContent: method. **It is far more
>   common to provide content for controllers by establishing a binding to
>   one of their exposed Controller Content bindings.**
>
> NSObjectController exposes a single binding for content called
>   **contentObject**. You can establish a binding from contentObject to any
>   object that is key-value-coding and key-value-observing compliant for
>   the keys that you intend to have the controller operate on.

From an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691287/how-do-i-bind-an-nstextfields-value-to-an-nsobjectcontrollers-content-without/10692706#10692706):

> For an NSObjectController, the selection is the content object.

Apparently, the selection @property of the NSObjectController is assigned the contentObject, which is the thing that enables you to do bindings.

More [generally](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002146-BCICADHC):

> NSObjectController and its subclasses ... support tracking of the
>   ***currently selected object*** or objects

I think ***currently selected object*** must mean the control that is selected in the View.

> There are two methods that are commonly used to access the objects
>   that are currently selected: selection and selectedObjects.

I think that with an NSObjectController, the selected control in the View is meaningless, and therefore the selection @property of the NSObjectController is assigned the contentObject.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing "the selection @property of the NSObjectController is assigned the contentObject, which is the thing that enables you to do bindings."  Both `selection` and `content` allow bindings, but selection is one-way.   Like I said in the comment, `selection` makes more sense as implemented by `NSArrayController` and `NSTreeController`.  Same goes for `addObject`, `removeObject`, and `newObject`.